# how to load this eBPF code to kernal with python?

Tags: ebpf

i was new to learn eBPF, and i meet a problem,how to load below code to linux kernal with python?

```
SEC("lsm/path_chmod")
int BPF_PROG(path_chmod, const struct path *path, umode_t mode) {
bpf_printk("Change mode of file name %s\n", path->dentry->d_iname);
return 0; }
```

anybody can help, thanks.

Comment: Where did you find this code? Did you check https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/?